# Trim First 4 Characters from Strings Inside a List

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "0001", 
    "stateIds" : ["GGGGHI", "GGGGCA", "GGGGMA", "GGGGNY"]
}
```

I want to remove GGGG from each element in the stateIds list in each document.

Expected Output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "0001", 
    "stateIds" : ["HI", "CA", "MA", "NY"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, and have a look in [substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)

```
{
    $project: {
      stateIds: {
        $map: {
          input: "$stateIds",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $substr: [
              "$$s",
              4,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Working [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yvHVkCPu1Ri)